# Comparing random samples using bootstrapping (to determine minimum sample size)

Tags: r, size, sample

Im looking for a faster way to compare random samples using a bootstrapping method

At the moment my code takes a sample size, then takes 100 different random samples. It records the mean in each of them. Then it takes a slightly larger sample size, and does the same thing. And so on.

The purpose of this is to find the minimum sample size needed to accurately represent my population

My code at the moment:

```
set.seed(124) 
mydata <- rnorm(10000, 1, 100) 
Summary_Table <- data.frame(0:0)

#generate list of sample sizes 
Sample.sizes <- seq(1, length(mydata), by = 100) 

#take 100 random samples of each size and record summary stats
for(i in 1:100) { 
 for(j in 1:length(Sample.sizes)) { 
  Random.Sample <- mydata[sample(1:length(mydata), Sample.sizes[j], replace=FALSE)] 
  Summary_Table[j,i] <- mean(Random.Sample) # - median(Random.Sample)) / sd(Random.Sample) 
 } 
}
```

Trouble is this take 15 mins to run with the dataset I am using - is there a quicker way that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider parallelizing it.  E.g.

```
getSumStat <- function(size) {
  mean(mydata[sample(1:length(mydata), size, replace=FALSE)])
}

library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(getOption("cl.cores", 3))
clusterExport(cl, varlist=c("getSumStat", "mydata"))
out <- parSapply(cl, Sample.sizes, function(j) replicate(100, getSumStat(j)))
stopCluster(cl)
```